# AudioKit / AVAudioEngine play nodes in sequence

Tags: buffer, audiokit, avaudioengine

I have some audio playing with Audiokit / AVAudioEngine and I would like to be able to play one node after another without any gaps. Here is what I have so far.

```
var file:AKAudioFile!
    var node:AKPlayer!
    var node1:AKPlayer!
    var mixer:AKMixer!

    func playInSequence()
    {
        do
        {
            file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Song.m4a", baseDir: .resources)

            node = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
            node.startTime = 10
            node.endTime = 20
            node.buffering = .dynamic
            node.prepare()
            node.completionHandler =
            {
                print("node complete");
            }

            node1 = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
            node1.startTime = 20
            node1.endTime = 30
            node1.buffering = .dynamic
            node1.prepare()
            node1.completionHandler =
            {
                print("node1 complete");
            }

            mixer = AKMixer(node, node1)

            AudioKit.output = mixer

            try AudioKit.start()

            let future = AVAudioTime.now()
            node.play(at: future)

            let future2 = AVAudioTime.now() + 10
            node1.play(at: future2)
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Please forgive me if I'm doing it all wrong. I really don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Is it a requirement to have two nodes or could you use a single instance of `AVAudioPlayerNode` in an `AVAudioEngine`?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be. I may be looking at this the wrong way as I've only just been learning about AVAudioEngine. The reason I wanted to use two single nodes is so that I can jump around an audio file without any latency and thats how I thought it would be done.

Comment: You'd like to implement seeking?

Comment: Sort of. I have a song that I will allow the user to create markers throughout. When they start playing the song they will be able to tap which marker to go to next. Once the player finishes playing a section it will go to the next chosen section. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh, I see now.. once the node has started I can seek around without any issues. I thought I had to create buffers for every place that I wanted to seek to.